# Looking for an adware removal tool

Tags: antivirus

Hi friends I am looking for a good adware removal tool
Any suggestions ?

Comment: [Read this](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information) and [edit] your question.

Answer (score 1):

As advised by [Jan Doggen](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/users/416/jan-doggen), you need to review your question after reading [this post](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information).

**Your question is entirely subjective**. Under no user case is there a 'best' anti-virus, things change, systems update in real-time, and user wants/needs differ.

Furthermore, following items have not been addressed:

- Operating System;
- Intended Budget;
- System Specifications (some AVs are really resource intensive....*McAfee*) and;
- Other requirements.

None the less, I am sure there are a number of people whom will review this question in the hopes of cleaning their PC. So, I'll answer it as nicely as I can.

---

**Linux/Unix Systems**

If you're running Linux, there are a few options. My suggestion here would be to not use [ClamAV](http://blog.clamav.net/), and take a more enterprise approach with [Sophos](https://www.sophos.com/en-us/products/free-tools/sophos-antivirus-for-linux.aspx) or Bitdefender.

Read this *old* [post on Linux Anti-Virus](https://askubuntu.com/questions/399351/linux-anti-virus/399354#399354) debating whether you need an AV or not; depending on the use of the system depends on the needs of the user. In an ever-evolving world of threats, providing your root password to a pop-up can open you up to heaps of back-doors, for example.

Please note, I have used **none** of the following products. Please look into their features and reviews independently.

*Current options*
- [ClamAV](https://www.clamav.net/);

- [Sophos](https://www.sophos.com/en-us/products/); (Installation guide may be depreciated: [Installing Sophos on Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/645097/installing-sophos-anti-virus))
- [Comodo](https://www.comodo.com/home/internet-security/antivirus-for-linux.php);
- [Chkrootkit](http://www.chkrootkit.org/);
- [FProt](http://www.f-prot.com/products/home_use/linux/) and;
- [Bitdefender](http://www.bitdefender.com/business/antivirus-for-unices.html)

There are [many other options available to you as well](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux). In unison with an Anti-Virus system, you should also use a [Firewall](http://www.techradar.com/news/6-best-free-linux-firewalls-of-2017), and u[nderstanding the implications of running apps as root](https://www.howtogeek.com/124950/htg-explains-why-you-shouldnt-log-into-your-linux-system-as-root/).

---

**Windows Server/Client**

If you're running Windows, then there are a plethora of tools readily available for your use; [check the following table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows).

Regarding Security on a Windows PC , there are several key "tools" you *should* look for:

- Real Time protection, coined "[On Access Scanner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_protection)";
- [Heuristic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antivirus_software#Real-time_protection);
- [Client Firewall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firewall_(computing));
- [Intrusion protection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intrusion_detection_system) and [detection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intrusion_detection_system) and
- [Content Control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content-control_software) (Web Filtering);

An example of a *free* tool that implements Web Inspection, and IDS:

- [Recommendations for Anti-Virus and Firewall](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/35520/recommendations-for-anti-virus-and-firewall/35529#35529)
- [Non subscription based firewalls](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/43482/non-subscription-based-firewalls/43491#43491)

With all Windows Anti-Virus, I use [AVComparatives](https://www.av-comparatives.org) to read and review my programs. You can view their latest results for the tests [here](https://chart.av-comparatives.org/chart1.php).

I would also recommend you read the following article(s):

- [Is it worth getting paid anti-virus?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/49699/is-it-worth-it-to-get-paid-anti-virus-software)
- [Can I safely trust my anti-virus?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/25319/can-i-safely-trust-my-anti-virus-protection)

---

**Mac OSX**

The same can be applied to Mac OSX as Windows and Linux. There is no need to go into detail here.

---

Back in "the old days", I use to use [SuperAntiSpyware](http://www.superantispyware.com/) because it was cheap, lightweight and rather effective. I've just installed the trial, and after 1 minute of scanning, note the following:

[image: Super Anti Spyware]

Further investigation shows these seem to be [legitimate cookies that "track me"](https://www.f-secure.com/sw-desc/tracking_cookie.shtml) (**not** spyware programs):

[image: Found Cookies]

However, to properly "secure" a system, there need to be multiple layers of security:

- Regular backups of your personal files;
- Current anti-virus;
- Secure Firewall;
- User administration;
- Web Protection and;
- Data encryption.

These items, when employed, help further secure your PC.

**Related questions**

- [Backup and sync few important files to cloud](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/39355/backup-and-sync-few-important-files-to-cloud/45985#45985)
- [Software to password-protect individual folder(s) on Windows 7](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/37033/software-to-password-protect-individual-folders-on-windows-7/37063#37063)
- [CLI Based Backup Solution](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/36575/cli-based-backup-solution)
- [Free/ AUD Backup Solution](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/24908/free-aud-backup-solution)
- [Encrypt folder Windows 7 home](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/5630/encrypt-folder-windows-7-home)
- [Mechanism of delivery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_virus#Infection_mechanism)

Answer (score 0):

Malwarebytes is considered the best for a Mac. There is probably a PC version as well. It's certainly worth checking. It will scan your disk for malware and also run in the background if desired to check incoming problems.